# searching and adding a python list

Tags: python, list

I have a TList which is a list of lists. I would like to add new items to the list if they are  not present before. For instance if item I is not present, then add to Tlist otherwise skip.Is there a more pythonic way of doing it ? Note : At first TList may be empty and elements are  added in this code. After adding Z for example,   TList = [ [A,B,C],[D,F,G],[H,I,J],[Z,aa,bb]]. The other elements are based on calculations on Z.

```
    item = 'C'  # for example this item will given by user
    TList = [ [A,B,C],[D,F,G],[H,I,J]]
    if not TList:  
        ## do something
        # check if files not previously present in our TList and then add to our TList
    elif item  not in zip(*TList)[0]: 
         ## do something
```

Comment: What would be the result of adding a new entry (call it `Z`) to the `TList` above?

Comment: @aix I have edited the question to add this information

Comment: @user: It seems like you want the functionality of a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). Is that correct?

Comment: @Bjorn may be set can be used.I had thought of that. Later this data structure would be searched for elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it would appear that the first entry in each sublist is a key of some sort, and the remaining entries are somehow derived from that key, a dictionary might be a more suitable data structure:

```
vals = {'A': ['B','C'], 'D':['F','G'], 'H':['I','J']}
if 'Z' in vals:
  print 'found Z'
else:
  vals['Z'] = ['aa','bb']
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to keep the same data structure, something like this should work:

```
# create a set of already seen items
seen = set(zip(*TList)[:1])

# now start adding new items
if item not in seen:
    seen.add(item)
    # add new sublist to TList
```

Comment: Would'nt there be a exception if TList is empty ?

Comment: @user974168. yes, sorry - i just did a quick copy & paste. i've corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

@aix made a good suggestion to use a dict as your data structure; It seems to fit your use case well.

Consider wrapping up the value checking (i.e. 'Does it exist?') and the calculation of the derived values ('aa' and 'bb' in your example?).

```
class TList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.data)

    def set(self, key):
        if key not in self:
            self.data[key] = self.do_something(key)

    def get(self, key):
        return self.data[key]

    def do_something(self, key):
        print('Calculating values')
        return ['aa', 'bb']

    def as_old_list(self):
        return [[k, v[0], v[1]] for k, v in self.data.iteritems()]

t = TList()

## Add some values. If new, `do_something()` will be called
t.set('aval')
t.set('bval')
t.set('aval') ## Note, do_something() is not called

## Get a value
t.get('aval')

## 'in ' tests work
'aval' in t

## Give you back your old data structure
t.as_old_list()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using sets and set.union:

```
a = set(1,2,3)
b = set(4,5,6)
c = set()
master = [a,b,c]
if 2 in set.union(*master):
  #Found it, do something
else:
  #Not in set, do something else
```

If the reason for testing for membership is simply to avoid adding an entry twice, the set structure uses a.add(12) to add something to a set, but only add it once, thus eliminating the need to test. Thus the following:

```
>>> a=set()
>>> a.add(1)
>>> a
set([1])
>>> a.add(1)
>>> a
set([1])
```

If you need the set elsewhere as a list you simply say "list(a)" to get "a" as a list, or "tuple(a)" to get it as a tuple.